# how can i deploy my Dapp?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, truffle, ganache, testnets

what if I have deployed my smart contract on truffle and used ganache to deploy the same and i havn't used any test network, so if I go to deploy it on netlify to demonstrate the same will it work??

Comment: Ganache is a local testnetwork, and any testing on Truffle happens on local testnet.
You can make Dapp work locally on your computer, but you'd have to deploy it on a proper network to use Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

No, truffle or ganache are local environments, the same as you can think of localhost.

To make your dapp usable by other people you should deploy the contracts on any public testnet like Goerli,sepolia or any L2 testnets like Mumbai, optimism goerli, etc. I already assume that you have written the logic for connecting wallets and switching networks.